# Is = allowed in query params?

Tags: uri, ietf

Is this a "legal" URI query?

```
?query=username=="john_d"
```

Notice it has `==` in its value

On the one hand, it's recognized as a sub-delimiter character and hence reserved as per RFC 3986:

> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
> / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

On the other hand, a similar param value is mentioned in the [FIQL draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-atompub-fiql-00#section-4)

```
http://example.com/feed.atom?query=title==*new*,author==bob*
```

So should such query params be validated away by application utilities?